# A class that store all the objects

Tags: java, object, interface

I am writing a Java program. I have a LoanItem is super class, Movie and Book are subclass of LoanItem. Equipment is super class, Calculator and PC are subclass of Equipment. I also have a interface class called Library. Now I need to create a LibraryCollectItem (must use an array of 10 cells) that stores all items of type Library. It means the LibraryCollectItem will store all LoanItem objects and Equipment objects such as Movie, Book, Calculator, and PC. I am stuck and confusing at how to create the LibraryCollectItem, any idea? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your diagram isn't completely correct, and in some places your description doesn't match your diagram. Also, you should give it a try first and then ask questions where face some problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about an array

```
Library[] instances = new Library[10];

instances [0] = new Equipment (someString);
instances [1] = new LoanItem (someString, someId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have LibraryItem Class which will have Equipment and Loan Item as instance fields and its setters and getters .

Library[] instances = new LibraryItem[10];

instances[0] = new LibraryItem();

LoanItem loanObj =new Movie();
Equipment equip = new Calc();

instances[0].setLoanItem(loanObj);
instance[0].setEquipment(equip);
.
.
.
so on

Note: I am posting my answer from mobile hence cant format the code .... Contrl+K doesnt work here :)